# Fontawesome icons need to be next to each other horizontally

Tags: html, css, icons, alignment, font-awesome

I need 3 fontawesome square icons to be right next to one another. I can't figure out how to get them next to each other horizontally and I've tried display:inline-block

HTML:

```
 <div class="fa">
                    <a target="_blank" href="https://www.google.co.uk/">
                        <i class="fa fa-linkedin-square fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </a>
                    <a target="_blank" href="https://www.google.co.uk/">
                        <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </a>
                    <a target="_blank" href="https://www.google.co.uk/">
                        <i class="fa fa-github-square fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </a>

                    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/7c396dc5cb.js"></script>
                </div>
```

CSS:

```
.fa {
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    list-style-type:none;
}


.fa-linkedin-square {
    opacity: 0.4;
}

.fa-linkedin-square:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.fa-envelope {
    opacity: 0.4;
}

.fa-envelope:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.fa-github-square {
opacity: 0.4;
}

.fa-github-square:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Please include a fiddle or a codepen if possible! Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must just do this and remove `inline_block`

```
.fa {
      display: flex;
 }
```

If anything else you want, tell what you want to do.

Comment: and you can delete a `text-align: center;` and use this -> `align-item:center;`.

Comment: Instead of adding it to .fa, I had to add it to the class that contained all of the icons --> this was where I was going wrong for anyone else who needs this :D